# How to pass JSON data to another view controller from login function using post method?

Tags: ios, json, swift3, oauth, alamofire

I m having blank data in another view controller, I can pass data between table view controller but I m having a problem to parse data from login method and pass access token or username from JSON?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var username_textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password_textfield: UITextField!
var logindata : [Login] = []
 var myResponse  :   JSON    =   nil
func getlogin(){
        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        let parameters = [

            "UserName": username_textfield.text! as String,
            "Password": password_textfield.text! as String,
            "grant_type": "password",
            ]


        //        let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token")!
        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case.success(let data):
                print("success",data)
                 let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                if statusCode == 200{
                    self.view.makeToast(message: "Welcome !!")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainview", sender: self)

                }else{
                    self.view.makeToast(message: "Username or password invalid")
                }
                self.myResponse = JSON(data)
            let login = Login(loginJson: self.myResponse)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pass_data", sender: login)
            })


            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }
```

**passing data to another view controller**

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pass_data" {
        if let eventsVC = segue.destination as? MenuDrawerViewController,
            let loginData = sender as? Login {
            eventsVC.login_details = loginData
        }
    }
}
```

**i have model class**

```
class Login{

    var access_token = String()
    var token_type = String()
    var expire_in = String()
    var username = String()
    var masterid = String()
    var name = String()
    var access = String()
    var issued = String()
    var expries = String()

    init(loginJson:JSON){
    self.access_token = loginJson["access_token"].stringValue
        self.token_type = loginJson["token_type"].stringValue
        self.expire_in = loginJson["expires_in"].stringValue
        self.username = loginJson["userName"].stringValue
        self.masterid = loginJson["MasterID"].stringValue
        self.name = loginJson["Name"].stringValue
        self.access = loginJson["Access"].stringValue
        self.issued = loginJson[".issued"].stringValue
        self.expries = loginJson[".expires"].stringValue
    }


}
```

**and in second view controller I have call class like  this**

```
class MenuDrawerViewController: UIViewController {
var login_details : Login?
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        titlename_text.text = login_details?.name
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

> I m a bit confused where I'm getting wrong or I'm doing it in wrong
>   way, how it can be solved?

i want to pass data through navigation controller and without using navigation controller data is passed so i try this function to pass and it giving me error on "`if let detailController`" condition

```
override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "dashboard" {
            let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
           if let detailController = navController.topViewController as! ViewController,
            let loginData = sender as? Login {
                detailController.login_details = loginData
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting multiple login object ? Array of User if not you need to show us your JSON response

Comment: no i will get single object while login username, password and it access me access token , name

Comment: success {
    ".expires" = "Thu, 29 Jun 2017 05:19:17 GMT";
    ".issued" = "Wed, 28 Jun 2017 05:19:17 GMT";
    Access = 4;
    MasterID = S0095;
    Name = "Calvin Patterson";
    "access_token" = "GipKW2FcKD-YFF_2vv_HtVzeI6ziBcKeI9PuNFHtGFJYFU_A1vDhnJcvF-ad0rMmKR7TpOESoQl1WdQ588gJoWS8BjJRUi1-qnhOcJR5fLjHio5Bv-SMavIv4BYMV17Akq3s3v7HG7p_5ZTbUMsqga7ewB3JdAt_jaiKcuShku2Bf3cq0sYf1CIABsqmRjbVpzsGX30K5mIEF";
    "expires_in" = 86399;
    "token_type" = bearer;
    userName = cal0095;
}

Comment: i have success JSON data now i want to parse that name and acces token to another view ?

Comment: Check my below solution

Comment: What is the error ? also why you are casting `topViewController` to `ViewController` instead of 
`MenuDrawerViewController`

Comment: error is data is not passing cause i have embed in navigation controller in my view Controller so it giving me error and passing data to another VC

Comment: In my view Controller **so it giving me error**, what is the error? I get that you have embed Your `MenuDrawerViewController` with `NavigationController` then why you are casting `topViewController` to `ViewController` instead of `MenuDrawerViewController`.

Comment: No sir i  am passing data to viewController not in  MenuDrawerViewController and error is "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not View Controller "

Comment: Change `as!` with `as?` because you are working with if let

Comment: it works sir thanks a lot and can we pass data to multiple controller from performsegue

Comment: No that possible until you work with `UITabbar`

Comment: can i edit my question u can see and give me some suggestion how it can be done .

Comment: I think now you need to ask a new question instead of editing this one and put the link of it, will look for it. If I have solution will post one for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147908/discussion-between-bikesh-thakur-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For loop` here is unnecessary because you are not getting array of Login data what you need is to directly use `self.myResponse` to make object of `Login`. Also you are performing segue twice with different identifier perform segue to specific identifier with your corresponding  destination controller.

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
        case.success(let data):
            print("success",data)
            let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
            if statusCode == 200{
                self.view.makeToast(message: "Welcome !!")
            }else{
                self.view.makeToast(message: "Username or password invalid")
            }
            self.myResponse = JSON(data)
            let login = Login(loginJson: self.myResponse)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pass_data", sender: login)
            })
        case.failure(let error):
            print("Not Success",error)
    }
}
```

Now make your `prepareForSegue` like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pass_data" {
        if let eventsVC = segue.destination as? MenuDrawerViewController,
           let loginData = sender as? Login {
              eventsVC.login_details = loginData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so in this method how can i pass to another view controller 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pass_data" {
            if let eventsVC = segue.destination as? MenuDrawerViewController {
//                 let passvalue : Login
                for   passvalue in logindata{
                        eventsVC.login_details = passvalue
                
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @BikeshThakur I have already added code of `prepareForSegue` you need to write it like that also with `performSegue` pass login object as sender like I have done in my solution

Comment: sorry i reload page late , and in MenuDrawerViewController how can it be called its showing me blank in lable name

Comment: @BikeshThakur Have you remove the perform segue call with `mainview` because in you question code you are performing segue with two different identifier if it still not works then edit your question with your current trying code with preparefor segue

Comment: @BikeshThakur You still haven't remove the for loop also not removed the perform segue from if condition `if statusCode == 200{` check my solution once again and you need to make your success case same Like my one

Comment: oh yeah that was great i was just confused and thanks a lot sir that was great THANKS SIR i was doing this stuff since 2 days . thanks

Comment: @BikeshThakur Welcome mate :) Glad it works for you :)

Comment: can i ask u one question sir how can we pass using storyboard id instead of performsegue ** self.myResponse = JSON(data)
                let login = Login(loginJson: self.myResponse)  if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboard") as? ViewController {
                            viewController.login_details = login
                            if let navigator = self.navigationController {
                                navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)  }
                        }

Comment: @BikeshThakur Then you need to create the VIewController instance using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier)` like this  `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! MenuDrawerViewController; vc.login_details = loginData; self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: @BikeshThakur What error you are taking about don't add code in comment here remove this all comment and edit your question with code that you are currently trying and explain whats not working

Comment: sir can give me some suggestion on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897319/plot-the-dynamic-data-using-charts-library?noredirect=1#comment76774028_44897319