# Not working - Registering User in Api Programatically in Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I'm trying to register a user in my API. When I do it in Postman, it registers the user and returns the status as true and message as User Created, but when I try to create a new user from swift programatically it always shows User already exists (giving false response), even though it is not registered. I'm Using Swift 4 Xcode 9.

The almost same code work works for Sign In Api, but not working for User Registration. Also, after I register that user through postman in Api, it works perfectly fine for Login. So I'm not getting what the problem is with RegisterUser. Code shows no error.

Here is my code for registeringUser:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class RegisterUserViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Cancel button tapped")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       print("Sign up button tapped")


        // Validate required fields are not empty
        if (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (emailAddressTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!
        {
            // Display Alert message and return
            displayMessage(userMessage: "All fields are quired to fill in")
            return
        }

        // Validate password
        if ((passwordTextField.text?.elementsEqual(repeatPasswordTextField.text!))! != true)
        {
            // Display alert message and return
            displayMessage(userMessage: "Please make sure that passwords match")
            return
        }



        let userdefault = UserDefaults.standard
        userdefault.set(emailAddressTextField.text, forKey: "email_id")
        //userdefault.set(emailAddressTextField, forKey: "email_id")
         print("email_id",emailAddressTextField.text)

        //print("email_address",userdefault.string(forKey: "email_id"))


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://horn.hostingduty.com/api/v1/app_adduser")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        print("its working")
        let postString =    "first_name=\(firstNameTextField.text)";
        "last_name=\(lastNameTextField.text)";
        "email_id=\(emailAddressTextField.text)";
        "password=\(passwordTextField.text)"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }



            var responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            if(responseString?.contains("true"))!{

                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {

                        let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                        appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage

                }

          print("status = true")

            }
            else{

                                DispatchQueue.main.async
                                    {

                                        self.showToast(message: "Already exists !! ")
                                    }
                print("Status = false")

            }
        }

         task.resume()


    }
    func displayMessage(userMessage:String) -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {}
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                    // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
                    print("Ok button tapped")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }

}
```

Comment: poststring declaretion is wrong

Comment: What type of content is this? is it form encoded or Json?

Comment: encoded @Fahadsk

Comment: Could you post the right declaration please? @Jaydip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func loginApi() {


    let userName = userNameText?.text ?? ""
    print(userName)
    let password = passwordText?.text ?? ""
    print(password)
    let params = [

        "emailId"      :  userName as Any,
        "password"     :  password as Any,

        ] 


    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request("your url", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent))
        .validate(statusCode: [200, 201])
        .responseJSON {
             [unowned self] (response) in



                switch(response.result) {
                case .success:
                    guard let json = response.result.value as! 
               [String:Any]? else{ return}
                    print("Response \(json)")
                    if let data = json["data"] as! [String:Any]?{
                     let email_id : String = email_id
                                userdefault.set(emailAddressTextField.text, forKey: "email_id")
                                print(email_id)
                                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                          let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage
                            }

                        }

                    }


                case .failure(let err):
                    self.showNormalAlertWithTitle(NSLocalizedString("Alert!", comment: ""), message:NSLocalizedString("Please enter valid username or password", comment: ""))
                    print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                    break

                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: But this looks totally different from my code. Is there anything wrong with my code? Because it doesn't give any error and also it works with Sign In.

Comment: Is this the answer for sign in or sign up? because there are more params for signing up. Or does it work with both/

Comment: u can pass more parameters in your parameter

Comment: both the codes are correct the difference is I am using Alamofire and you are urlsession to pass api. You used Alamofire pod in your project that's the reason i give this answer. Its far easier to use alamofire rather than urlsession

Comment: welcome if you have any issue with my code you can tell

Comment: +1. I was stuck here for so long. Just one thing, it doesn't seague to homepage, even though we have given the seague condition in the code.

Comment: I have added this seague condition. But it doesn't go to that view controller . 

DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                    let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage
                            }

Comment: push your controller self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourVc, animated: true) in last

Comment: Where exactly? Tried adding it after      let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage

but not working.

Comment: if you just wanna go to the next view controller just simply add push method below nsuserdefault. See the code again maybe this could help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794383/how-to-pass-json-data-to-another-view-controller-from-login-function-using-post

Comment: Can you please check with this code if it displays the alert message box saying 'Already exists' if user is not registered, or segues to home page if user is registered? Its not working with mine so. User registration problem is solved, just this new problem has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

You should add header to your request and send proper url encoded key/values

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
```

And change your post string as

```
let postString = "first_name=\(firstNameTextField.text)&" +
        "last_name=\(lastNameTextField.text)&" +
        "email_id=\(emailAddressTextField.text)&" +
        "password=\(passwordTextField.text)"

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
```

**UPDATE**

```
func callApi(){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://horn.hostingduty.com/api/v1/app_adduser")!)
        request.httpMethod = "post"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        print("its working")
        let postString =    "first_name=test&" +
        "last_name=test&" +
        "email_id=test@abc.vom&" +
        "password=123&"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            var responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            if(responseString?.contains("true"))!{
                print("status = true")
            }
            else{
                print("Status = false")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the code as you said, but still no luck.

Comment: I have to copy-paste your provided request.setValue as it is right?

Comment: What error you are getting? try printing your error and response values.

Comment: I am not getting any error that's what. It should give response true and message as 'user created', but everytime it just gives response false and message 'user already exists' (as set in api)

private effective user settings.
Sign up button tapped
email_id Optional("hihi@gmail.com")
its working
responseString = Optional("{\"status\":\"false\",\"message\":\"SORRY :-( This Email ID is already exists..!!\"}")
Status = false

Comment: Have you tried with any other email id ? also is this the error you were previously getting?

Comment: Yes I have tried. and been getting the same response. Even if i try any new email id, it gives the same response, And then when I give it through postman in Api, it accepts and registers the user, which later works fine with logging in. So Api has no problem accepting it, its somewhere in the code that i am missing something don't know.

Comment: I have just tried with the above code and it worked, may be you were not sending proper values in post, just check it out updated answer and let me know

Comment: Can you please check with this code if it displays the alert message box saying 'Already exists' if user is not registered, or segues to home page if user is registered? Its not working with mine so. User registration problem is solved, just this new problem has arrived